# Exclude mysql-connector jar from war file in Gradle

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I am using 
providedCompile("mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.11") 
but still can see this jar in lib-provided in my war file .
 I want to exclude this from my jar file. I also tried provideRuntime but no success.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to use "compileOnly" instead of "providedCompile" ?
Difference between both configurations is explained in this issue: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/1171

Comment: It does remove jars from runtime but its causing issues running project locally.